# Obtener el número más grande y el más pequeño entre las propiedades de un objeto

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

¿Cómo se puede hacer para obtener el número más grande y el más pequeño de entre las propiedades de un objeto cómo el siguiente?

```
var animales = {
  caballos: 10,
  perros: 4,
  pez_espada: 1,
  tortugas: 3,
  gatos: 6,
  hipopotamos: 4,
  elefantes: 4
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar los métodos [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries) para obtener las propiedades en forma de un array y [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para obtener el de mayor o menor valor.

De esta forma no solo obtienes los valores mayor o menor, también obtienes el nombre de la propiedad a la que pertenecen.

```js
var animales = {
  caballos: 10,
  perros: 4,
  pez_espada: 1,
  tortugas: 3,
  gatos: 6,
  hipopotamos: 4,
  elefantes: 4
}

var max = Object.entries(animales).reduce(function(prev, curr){
  return prev[1] > curr[1] ? prev : curr;
});

var min = Object.entries(animales).reduce(function(prev, curr){
  return prev[1] < curr[1] ? prev : curr;
});

console.log('La propiedad con el mayor valor es', max[0], 'y su valor es', max[1]);
console.log('La propiedad con el menor valor es', min[0], 'y su valor es', min[1]);
```

El resultado que se imprime en consola es:

`La propiedad con el mayor valor es caballos y su valor es 10`

`La propiedad con el menor valor es pez_espada y su valor es 1`

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer de este modo utilizando `forEach` y `Object.keys`

```js
var animales = {
  caballos: 10,
  perros: 4,
  pez_espada: 1,
  tortugas: 3,
  gatos: 6,
  hipopotamos: 4,
  elefantes: 4
}

var numero_mayor = 0;

Object.keys(animales).forEach(key => {
  if (animales[key] > numero_mayor) numero_mayor = animales[key];

})

var numero_menor = numero_mayor;

Object.keys(animales).forEach(key => {
  if (animales[key] < numero_menor) numero_menor = animales[key];

})

console.log("número mayor: ", numero_mayor);
console.log("número menor: ", numero_menor);
```